# Alarm function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager, alarm

Can anyone how to do Alarm notification in flutter using SQLite is there any packages I used Alarm manager but its not working properly

When I used Alarm manager function i unable to get desired output also for notification sound what packages can be used

Comment: Barely context on your post. Share what you've tried and which are not working with codes so people will get your problem and give you the solutions much easier

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.